# Use WNS for windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, mpns

Is WNS available for windows phone 8 devices. If yes, where can I find some good documentation to use it.

I was about to use MPNS but [here](https://github.com/jeffwilcox/mpns) it says Microsoft is Sunsetting MPNS from Windows Phone 8.1. But when I looked for the documentation, it looks like it is not available yet to use with windows phone apps.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [official MPNS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402558%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) (which was updated this month) still states that MPNS applies to Windows Phone 8.1.

> **Push notifications for Windows Phone 8**
>
> **May 10, 2014**
>
> Applies to: Windows Phone 8 **and Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1** |
>   Windows Phone OS 7.1
>
> The Microsoft Push Notification Service in Windows Phone is an
>   asynchronous, best-effort service that offers third-party developers a
>   channel to send data to a Windows Phone app from a cloud service in a
>   power-efficient manner.

However, [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn642085%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), which was updated on the same date as the previous quote, says you can choose either MPNS or WNS for Windows Phone 8.1 apps.

> **Choosing MPNS or WNS for a Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 app**
>
> **May 10, 2014**
>
> When building a Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 app, you have a choice
>   to make about what push notification service your app will use. A push
>   notification service is an asynchronous service that provides a
>   channel you can use to send data from a cloud service to your app in a
>   power-efficient manner. In Windows Phone 8, the Microsoft Push
>   Notification Service (MPNS) was the push notification platform you
>   could use. In Windows Phone 8.1, the Windows Notification Service
>   (WNS) is now supported. This is the same service used by all Windows
>   Store apps. You can use either platform in a Silverlight 8.1 app. This
>   topic gives you the information you need to make an informed decision
>   about which notification service platform to use in your Silverlight
>   8.1 app.

So if you are creating a new Windows Phone app for Windows Phone 8.1, you are advised to use WNS, which has more features :

> The following lists some of the benefits of using WNS and the Windows
>   Runtime APIs for tiles, toast and badges in your Silverlight 8.1 app.
>
> - Notifications are delivered within 5 seconds to devices connected to a network
> - No more certifications to manage. WNS uses OAuth instead of SSL certification.
> - The same service and APIs can be used for all Windows Phone Store apps, offering the potential for code sharing/reuse and lower
>     maintenance costs.
> - Periodic polling - Update tiles and badges by periodically polling for content updates from a cloud service.
> - Tile notification queue - The ability of a tile to display a rotation of up to 5 updates.
> - Larger tile template catalog - Over 40 templates to choose a tile layout suited to your needs.
> - Raw notifications - The ability to wake up your app or start a background task by sending it a raw notification.
> - Expiration time on a tile update - By setting an expiration time, the tile will revert to its default.
> - Manage your toast notifications in action center - You can use the new APIs to send notifications directly into action center, categorize
>     notifications and selectively remove and replace notifications in
>     action center.

Comment: Thanks a lot for making things clear. Since I am targeting Windows Phone 8.0, I conclude that it is safer to use MPNS.